# Server side validation to limit file upload size to 5mb

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I want to add a custom validator ,which ensures that the file upload size should not be greater than 5MB.

Comment: I think [this should be your answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540901/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Define the size using the **`maxRequestLength`** attribute of the `<httpRuntime>`  tag (within the `<system.web>` tag ) of **web.config** file.

ex:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime 
      ...
      maxRequestLength="5242880"   //Number of Bytes (5MB)
      ...
    />
   ...
</system.web>
```

**Showing an alert to the user when updating large file**

In the file uploading event handler, check for the 'ContentLength' of the 'PostedFile'.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 5242880)
{
   // Relevant error message goes here...
}
```

It will be useful to refer to the [FileUploadClass MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well.

Comment: hi CRoshanLGI want to give an error message to th euser if he does so,and with your solution this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Prkh  I've edited the answer. Please let me know whether this worked and if you need more help.

Comment: @CRoshanLGI your answer actually makes this work,but this happens on button_click event i.e page load will be fired.I want that the message can be displayed as soon as the user selects a file before the click event of the button.

Comment: @Prkh I can understand what you expect to implement. You want to give the user an alert as soon as the file is selected (similar to a desktop app would react to users' actions). But this is _not_ possible in ASP.net since it is a server side language! The data must be passed to the server, in order to give some kind of response to the user. There is no way to detect whether a file is selected or not until some data is posted to the server side! **You will have to use the button click event (or some other similar event)!**